# Dapp: Ask mist to sign a transaction

Tags: transactions, mist, web3js, dapps

As I see it dapps can only be used from webbrowsers (apart from the outdated secret open source release of the mist browser or whatever that was called). That leaves the question how to send transactions from a dapp.

I was hoping that there would be a way to ask a mist wallet running at the same time to send/sign a transaction, which would then display the usual transaction summary and ask for the account password. However, I have not found anything like this.

Is there any way to send a transaction without handing the dapp the unlocked account data, which implies trusting the dapp with the whole account balance?

Answer (score 2):

The Mist browser that you mentioned is actually still in development and nearing beta stages.

In the meantime, [Metamask](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/metamask/nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn) is a browser extension that manages your keys and signs transactions locally. It will also be going into official beta very soon, but is already on the chrome store to try out.

Comment: Metamask looks useful. However it doesn't seem like it can import my existing keys. So I guess that doesn't solve the question of how to get mist users to be able to use a dapp.